# Close CMD within Ruby

Tags: ruby, cmd

I wrote a function in Ruby that hibernates, restarts, or shuts down the system based on the argument. Here's how it looks:

```
def sysaction(action)
  sleep 0.2
  if action == "h"
    countdown(60)
    `shutdown.exe /h`
  elsif action == "r"
    countdown(60)
    `shutdown.exe -r -f t 00`
  elsif action == "s"
    countdown(60)
    `shutdown.exe -s -f t 00`
  end
end
```

I want to add a piece of code that would exit the parent CMD windows instead. I couldn't find any solution without running the ruby script through a batch file. I tried the following commands:

```
`exit`
exec `exit`
system('exit')
`cmd /C exit`
```

But neither seems to work. Any way I can close the window from within Ruby?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with [tag:hibernate], no?

Comment: I guess you're right, I guess I got too focused on my function where it has to do a lot with hibernation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `FreeConsole` function:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683150(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/w/win32console-1.3.1/Win32/Console/API.html#method-c-FreeConsole

For example:

```
require 'win32console'

puts 'Hello, world!

# free console so it can be shut after the program terminates.
Win32::Console::API.FreeConsole
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that I don't want to use Win32Console as it creates problems with UTF-8 encoding in all strings which I am heavily relying on. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to kill all cmd.exe applications:

```
taskkill /f /im cmd.exe
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a solution, but I a little bit of overkill in my situation ;)